Which characters support the side they believe is illegitimate in the Dance of the Dragons?
In House of the Dragon, I've always assumed that the members of the two warring factions—the Blacks and the Greens—believed their side was legitimate and that their opponents were the actual usurpers of the Iron Throne. However, I was caught off guard by something Aemond Targaryen said in season 2, episode 1:

[My mother] blames me for starting this war after she plotted with my father's council to usurp his throne.

This quote suggests that Aemond actually believes his own side, the Greens, are the usurpers—yet he still fights for them. It got me thinking: Besides Aemond, are there other characters who've chosen a side while believing that side might not have the legitimate claim?
I'm curious if anyone knows of other examples, either from House of the Dragon or the source material, Fire & Blood, where characters fight for the Blacks or Greens despite thinking their faction might be illegitimate. To be clear, I'm not talking about characters who switched sides (voluntary or otherwise), turncloaks, and the like, but rather those who stuck with a faction they suspected might not have the legitimate claim to the Iron Throne.

Just to clarify, I'm specifically asking about characters during the Dance of the Dragons, which is the conflict shown in House of the Dragon. I'm not talking about characters in Game of Thrones, which take place much later in the timeline.

Leave "right" and "wrong" to the bible bashers, this is about power and who stands to gain from a change in leader.

I think it's pretty obvious that Otto knows Viserys wanted Rhaenyra to be queen but plotted to have it otherwise. So do a lot of the main hands in the Greens which is why everything was hush hush and rushed to begin with.
I think Allicent is supposed to feel similar to Otto in the book (though the books aren't exactly detailed story tellings of the event but more factual brief overviews). However, the show makes it seem like she believes Aegon is the rightful ruler due to a misunderstanding between her and Viserys.

In the series it's Alicent apparently, after what Rhaenyra told her in 2nd season (or at least she has strong doubts).
